# Put extra depending on the pressed shortcut

Tags: android, kotlin, android-shortcut

My Android app has 3 shortcuts. Depending on which shortcut was clicked, a message is sent via putExtra. The code is shown below.

```
val shortcutManager = getSystemService(
        context,
        ShortcutManager::class.java
)

val a: Intent
val b: Intent
val c: Intent

val mainIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, null, context, Class1::class.java)

a = mainIntent
a.putExtra( "THIS_IS_A",
        Class2::class.java.name
)

b = mainIntent
b.putExtra( "THIS_IS_B",
        Class3::class.java.name
)

c = mainIntent
c.putExtra("THIS IS C",
        Class4::class.java.name
)
val shortcutA = ShortcutInfo.Builder(context, "shortcutId")
        .setShortLabel("a")
        .setLongLabel("a")
        .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(context, icon))
        .setIntent(a)
        .build()
        ...
val shortcutC = ShortcutInfo.Builder(context, "shortcutIdC")
        .setShortLabel("c")
        .setLongLabel("c")
        .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(context, icon))
        .setIntent(c)
        .build()
shortcutManager!!.dynamicShortcuts = listOf(shortcutA, ..., shortcutC)
```

In this case, I am trying to send a unique message using putExtra by clicking on a certain shortcut, so that in the class where I send this data, depending on the value, to perform actions, but in this case only the last putExtra is always sent, i.e. "THIS_IS_C". Please help me figure out how by clicking on a certain element the necessary data was sent, i.e. by clicking on the first shortcut "THIS_IS_A" was sent, and by clicking on the third shortcut "THIS_IS_C" was sent?

Comment: You set a, b, and c to all be the same instance of Intent. You only called the Intent constructor once.

Comment: @Tenfour04 , Thank you, you helped me figure it out))
The following question arose: when the shortcut is clicked, it is checked if the user is authorized (data is taken from SharedPreferences), then redirecting to HomeActivity, and if not authorized, then redirecting to MainActivity. Created dynamic shortcuts, but works chaotically. Are there any examples of similar solutions, or do you know how to solve this?

Comment: I don't know of any examples of that specifically. Nowadays, Google recommends using a single Activity for the whole app and using the Navigation Component (where you set up a destination tree in a WYSIWYG/XML editor) to determine navigation to places in the Fragment stack.